# understand fork in c

Tags: c, fork

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [printf anomaly after “fork()”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork)
>   [Using fork with c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399145/using-fork-with-c)
>   [fork() branches more than expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11132868/fork-branches-more-than-expected)

I have this example of code, but I don't understand why this code print 00000000 and not 000000.

```
When i=0 , print 00
When i=1 , there is 4 process and it will print 0000.
```

This is the program:

```
 main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<2 ;i++){
        fork();
        printf("0");
    }
  }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [printf anomaly after "fork()"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530663/printf-anomaly-after-fork) or [Using fork with c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399145/using-fork-with-c) or many others...

Comment: Your program might be a little more enlightening if it `printf`'d `i` instead of 0.